# Force signal/slot hookup of not-yet-visible QML item on startup

Tags: c++, qt, qml

In Qt's QML language for writing GUI code, QML elements are (if I understand correctly) not actually created until they become visible. (**EDIT:** It sounds like the elements are *created* when the QML engine loads them, but it appears that signal/slot connections are not made unless the elements are *visible*.)

I have some QML elements (`LineSeries` objects from [`QtCharts`](http://doc.qt.io/QtCharts/index.html)) that record some data over time, and I would like them to start recording data as soon as my app starts up, even though the `ChartView` elements containing each series aren't immediately visible (users must navigate to a page containing these elements).

Is this possible?

One approach might be to keep each data series itself in some kind of `QVariantList` containing `QPointF`s in a global QML object, then dynamically assign it to the desired `LineSeries` object when the parent `ChartView` is instantiated. This might be possible using [`ChartView::createSeries`](http://doc.qt.io/QtCharts/qml-qtcharts-chartview.html#createSeries-method), though I believe the only way to populate the new series would be to call `ChartView::series()`  and pass that to some kind of `Q_INVOKABLE` method in my C++ backend that would populate the series.

**EDIT:** Not sure if this is relevant, but the GUI element I'm using for navigation (i.e. the reason the `ChartView` isn't visible on startup) is a `TabView`. The `ChartView` objects are not top-level `TabView` pages; they're a couple levels down.

**EDIT 2:** The answer below seems like it *should* work, but I get the rather unhelpful error `TypeError: Type error` when I try to implement it. I've [put together a minimal (non-)working example here](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/PublicPaste/tree/94730dc230615a5d8c4bf9c805689558427d5616/qml_chgparent) (use `qmlscene` to run it; I am using Qt 5.5).

**EDIT 3:** The above non-working version was [fixed by simply adding a property alias](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/PublicPaste/commit/2a93b24ec1fa8a5224e4225cec2731fad4411a39), thanks to Mitch's answer and comments.

Comment: QML deals with many other object types besides renderable objects deriving from `Item`. Given this, the notion of visibility simply doesn't apply to the basic engine behavior. Renderable objects are an extension to the core functionality.

Comment: @KubaOber Hmmmm. I'm using a TabView to hold the pages of the GUI, and the default start page is not the page with the ChartView objects in it. My `LineSeries` objects are populated by a signal/slot connection via a `Connections` element in the item containing my `ChartView`. Any idea why, when I open the appropriate tab for the first time, there's no data already present in the `LineSeries` objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items in Qt Quick are created as soon as the QML they reside in is loaded by the QML engine (even if they default to non-visible). The exception to this rule are items that dynamically load their content, like `Loader`.

In your edit, you said that you're using `TabView`. I think that the setup you have is something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 800
    height: 700
    visible: true

    TabView {
        id: sv
        anchors.fill: parent

        Tab {
            title: "Page 1"
        }

        Tab {
            title: "Page 2"
            ChartView {}
        }
    }
}
```

Try changing it to something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 800
    height: 700
    visible: true

    ChartView {
        id: chartView
        color: "red"
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: false

        Component.onCompleted: print("Monitoring data...")
    }

    TabView {
        id: sv
        anchors.fill: parent

        Tab {
            id: tab1
            title: "Page 1"
        }

        Tab {
            id: tab2
            title: "Page 2"
            onActiveChanged: {
                if (active) {
                    chartView.parent = tab2;
                    chartView.visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Tab`s are [basically just `Loader`s](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tab.html), so they have all of `Loader`'s API, including the `active` property. This property lets you know when that tab has been loaded. Before that stage, it's inaccessible.

When the tab becomes active, we reparent the `ChartView` to it so that it's displayed in the correct place, and then show it.

As you can see from the debug output, the `ChartView` is created at startup. You can move it somewhere else to control when it's loaded, or... use a `Loader`. :)

**EDIT:** Based on this answer and the discussion in the comments, OP has created a [small working example](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/PublicPaste/tree/master/qml_chgparent) that demonstrates how persistent items can be pre-loaded and re-parented.

Comment: QtCharts is not part of QtQuick; does your statement about visibility still apply to QtCharts elements? I'm storing data directly in the UI elements because the charts I'm displaying aren't much more than eye-candy (the "official" data is stored in an actual database), and I'd like the amount and types of data I store to be easily adjustable within QML (which isn't really possible if I have my backend cache the state).

Comment: `ChartView` is probably an `Item`, so yeah, it should apply.

Comment: Okay, so if the `ChartView` is created as soon as it's loaded, it seems like it's still not getting its signals and slots hooked up until the `TabView` page it's under is selected. If it's *visibility* that determines whether the signals/slots are actually connected on start-up, then your code won't change the behavior, so I'm not sure what you're saying the underlying problem is.

Comment: But you want to use the `ChartView` with a separate "page" in the `TabView`, right? So you need to make sure that the `ChartView` is created at the same time (or before) that page. You can move the `ChartView` outside of the `TabView` so that it's always available (but hidden), and then, when the user navigates to the page that would normally have the `ChartView` in it, set the `parent` property of the `ChartView` to that page (or some item in it, like an empty placeholder `Item`).

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit lost. Yes, the `ChartView` is on a "page" in the `TabView` that is *not* the default "page" (i.e. the page that appears on startup). But I'm not sure what the order of creation has to do with anything, since you said that the objects are all created when they're loaded (which happens before the `QApplication` is actually launched). When you say "move the `ChartView`...so that it's always available", what exactly do you mean by "available"? That seems to be the core of the issue; I'm not sure what "available" means in QML, hence why I thought it had to do with visibility.

Comment: I forget if you get notifications when an answer to your question is edited, so... I edited my answer. :)

Comment: I didn't! Thanks for the heads-up. Okay, so I think the key here is the `Loader` class (and the fact that `TabView` inherits from it); I didn't know there was a class that prevented the QML engine from loading all of its children immediately. I'm not sure the first part of your answer is all that relevant any more, so you might want to delete it. This has been very helpful, but at the moment I'm unable to get the solution to work due to scoping difficulties.

Comment: Okay, now I'm just getting `TypeError: TypeError`, which isn't exactly helpful. I've produced a [small example](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/PublicPaste/tree/master/qml_chgparent) that basically tries to do what you're suggesting, except that it uses the `Component.onCompleted` signal for the intended *parent* of the ChartView object (which in my example is just a rectangle) in order to trigger the change-of-parent. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: (You should be able to run the example using `qmlscene`.)

Comment: It helps to print the values that you're trying to access. In this case: `print(persistent, persistent.red_rect)` gives me `QQuickItem(0x46320b9110) undefined`, which says that `red_rect` isn't defined. If you look at `Persistent.qml`, and then `main.qml`, what's the difference? Hint: it's an alias. :D

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I've edited your answer to include my little demo code, now that it works.